# Stat: Probability to have one element of a combination identical to one element of another combination

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, random

For a business application, I currently have to provide the probability we are going to have an issue in one application.

- The combination is composed of `N` unique elements.
- Each element is randomly choosed(and randomly choosed until not already contained in the current combination)
- Each element can be choosed amongst `P` possibilities
- I have `C` combinations

With this given combination, I've to compute the odd to have one element of one combination contained in any other combination.

My stats lessons are a little bit old so I'm pretty sure I'm not taking this the right way.

Currently I was thinking that I've `N/P` chance to have a specific element. So would I be correct to think that I've `(C*N)/P` chance to have a common element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to choose $C$ sets of $N$ elements from $P$ elements such that all elements are different across combinations is

$$
\binom P{\underbrace{N,\ldots,N}_{C\text{ times}},P-CN}=\frac{P!}{N!^C(P-CN)!}\;.
$$

The total number of ways to choose $C$ sets of $N$ elements from $P$ elements is

$$
\binom PN^C=\frac{P!^C}{N!^C(P-N)!^C}\;.
$$

Thus the probability of not having a common element is

$$
\frac{(P-N)!^C}{P!^{C-1}(P-CN)!}\;.
$$

The probability of having a common element is one minus that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try that. For now I'm quite stuck with my calculator who doesn't like such high numbers($$P = 2*10^2$$)

Comment: @J4N: Use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I admit you lost me on the first line, but the solution is containing some things I was expecting. :)

Comment: @J4N: Yes, I wasn't sure how much to explain; if you want to understand the derivation, feel free to ask :-)